# How to not match string not containing two consecutive newlines

Tags: python, regex

Demo at [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/bF5fL3/4). I have the following text file (a bibtex .bbl file):

```
\bibitem[{\textit{Alfonsi et~al.}(2011{\natexlab{a}})\textit{Alfonsi, Spogli,
  De~Franceschi, Romano, Aquino, Dodson, and Mitchell}}]{alfonsi2011bcg}
Alfonsi, L., L.~Spogli, G.~De~Franceschi, V.~Romano, M.~Aquino, A.~Dodson, and
  C.~N. Mitchell (2011{\natexlab{a}}), Bipolar climatology of {GPS} ionospheric
  scintillation at solar minimum, \textit{Radio Science}, \textit{46}(3),
  \doi{10.1029/2010RS004571}.

\bibitem[{\textit{Alfonsi et~al.}(2011{\natexlab{b}})\textit{Alfonsi, Spogli,
  Tong, De~Franceschi, Romano, Bourdillon, Le~Huy, and
  Mitchell}}]{alfonsi2011gsa}
Alfonsi, L., L.~Spogli, J.~Tong, G.~De~Franceschi, V.~Romano, A.~Bourdillon,
  M.~Le~Huy, and C.~Mitchell (2011{\natexlab{b}}), {GPS} scintillation and
  {TEC} gradients at equatorial latitudes in april 2006, \textit{Advances in
  Space Research}, \textit{47}(10), 1750--1757,
  \doi{10.1016/j.asr.2010.04.020}.

\bibitem[{\textit{Anghel et~al.}(2008)\textit{Anghel, Astilean, Letia, and
  Komjathy}}]{anghel2008nrm}
Anghel, A., A.~Astilean, T.~Letia, and A.~Komjathy (2008), Near real-time
  monitoring of the ionosphere using dual frequency {GPS} data in a kalman
  filter approach, in \textit{{IEEE} International Conference on Automation,
  Quality and Testing, Robotics, 2008. {AQTR} 2008}, vol.~2, pp. 54--58,
  \doi{10.1109/AQTR.2008.4588793}.

\bibitem[{\textit{Baker and Wing}(1989)}]{baker1989nmc}
Baker, K.~B., and S.~Wing (1989), A new magnetic coordinate system for
  conjugate studies at high latitudes, \textit{Journal of Geophysical Research:
  Space Physics}, \textit{94}(A7), 9139--9143, \doi{10.1029/JA094iA07p09139}.
```

I want to match the whole `\bibitem` command for a single entry (with some capture groups) if I know the reference code at the end of the command. I use this regex, which works for the first entry, but not for the rest (second entry exemplified below):

```
\\bibitem\[{(.*?)\((.*?)\)(.*?)}\]{alfonsi2011gsa}
```

This doesn't work, since it matches everything from the start of the first `\bibitem` command to the end of the second `\bibitem` command. How can I match only the second `\bibitem` command? I have tried using a negative lookahead for `^$` and `\n\n`, but I couldn't get either to work - basically, I want the third `(.*?)` to match any string not including two consecutive newlines. (If there's any other way to do this, I'm all ears.)

Comment: why don't split by newline?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're getting at. Are you suggesting splitting on '\n\n' and doing a regex on each item?

Comment: yes, even if it will be more expensive

Comment: Yes, that would be possible. I would like a regex if it's possible, though (for various reasons pertaining to what exactly I'm making, which is a long story)

Comment: Not sure I get it completely, but using re.DOTALL maybe? ``_re_bibitem = re.compile(r"(\\bibitem(.*?))\n\n", re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)`` (Note the non-greedy modifier)

Comment: I'm already using DOTALL, and as stated in the question, I need to match some things inside the `\bibitem` command also (matching groups).

Comment: Are the first two lines in your example input actually on one line or two in your file?

Comment: Two lines, so I need to use DOTALL. The command may be split across an arbitrary number of lines.

Comment: what do you want to extract and is `{alfonsi2011bcg}` always at the end?

Comment: Yes, it's always at the end. I want to extract `\textit{Alfonsi et~al.}`, `2011{\natexlab{b}}`, and `\textit{Alfonsi, Spogli,
  Tong, De~Franceschi, Romano, Bourdillon, Le~Huy, and
  Mitchell}` (the last group might not exist, see the last entry in the example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use negative look-arounds (`?!`) to prevent the match from having multiple occurrences of 'bibitem'. With this, the match will start with the 'bibitem' which immediately precedes your reference code. This seems to work:

```
\\bibitem\[{(((?!bibitem).)*?)\((((?!bibitem).)*?)\)(((?!bibitem).)*?)}\]{alfonsi2011gsa}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what I ended up using: `\\bibitem\[{((?:(?!^$).)*?)\(((?:(?!^$).)*?)\)((?:(?!^$).)*?)}\]{alfonsi2011gsa}` (flags `ms`). I see now that my error was using the negative lookaround in only one of the groups. It should have been in all of them, since any of them was sufficient to include the newlines otherwise. I also removed a few extra capture groups from your regex, and changed `bibitem` to `^$` (so in case any name contains `bibitem` it will still work).

Answer (score 0):

regex is not my strong point but this will get all the content you want without reading all the content into memory at once:

```
from itertools import groupby
import re
with open("file.txt") as f:
    r = re.compile(r"\[{(.*?)\((.*?)\)(.*?)}\]\{alfonsi2011gsa\}")
    for k, v in groupby(map(str.strip, f), key=lambda x: bool(x.strip())):
        match = r.search("".join(v))
        if match:
             print(match.groups())


('\\textit{Alfonsi et~al.}', '2011{\\natexlab{b}}', '\\textit{Alfonsi, Spogli,Tong, De~Franceschi, Romano, Bourdillon, Le~Huy, andMitchell}')
```